# What are the some parvas of Mahabharata mentions about Lord Shiva's deeds?

Tags: mahabharata, shiva, parvati

Does Mahabharata mentions any story or part where he (Shiva) states himself as supreme Lord? And what are the some best conversations between Shiva & Parvati from Mahabharata?

Comment: And what are the some best conversations between Shiva & Parvati from Mahabharata?

It needs to be changed/removed from your question to not close your question as too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Conversations between Shiva & Parvati from Mahabharata.

Just like Tantra , there is such a discussions present in  [**Mahabharata**](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b106.htm)-Anushasana Parva-Chapters 141 -145 **Discussion of Shiva-Parvati** mostly  on  the topic of Dharma which includes Varnashrama Dharma, Raj Dharma etc. The topics like various doshas , Karmas , Shradha are also discussed.These four chapters are dedicated to this discussion.

Uama asked  Lord Shiva about characteristics of Dharma and how those who are not aware of Dharma  can follw it ?  Uma asked about duties of Dharma  of four different varnas  of men i.e. Brahmana , Kshatriya ,Vaishya and Shudra as well as common duties of all the people. 
Uma further asks about duties of Yogis ,ascetics , widows and those who are following various ashramas like Grihastha , Brahmacharya etc. She askes Shiva to clear her doubts about what is Dharma and Adharma , how should be a behaviour of a man which  will lead him toward Moksha or swarga. She aska shiva about various karmas and their outcomes or results. She asks about Dana or charity.

Below are the some of the questions aksed by Uma and answers given by  Maheshwara.P.290

> **Uma Said** - O chastiser of all foes, this doubt of mine. What indications has Religion or Duty been said to possess? How, indeed, do
>   men become unacquainted with the details of Religion or Duty to
>   succeed in observing them? O puissant lord, O thou that art conversant
>   with Religion, do thou tell me this.
>
> **"Maheswara said"**, - 'Abstention from injury, truthfulness of speech, compassion towards all beings, tranquillity of soul, and the
>   making of gifts to the best of one's power, are the foremost duties of
>   the householder. Abstention from sexual congress with the spouses of
>   other men, protection of the wealth and the woman committed to one's
>   charge, unwillingness to appropriate what is not given to one, and
>   avoidance of honey and meat,--these are the five chief duties. Indeed,
>   Religion or Duty has many branches all of which are fraught with
>   happiness. Even these are the duties which these embodied creatures
>   who regard duty as superior should observe and practise. Even these
>   are the sources of merit.'
>
> ---
>
> **Uma said**, O holy one, I wish to ask thee another question about which I have great doubts. It behoveth thee to answer it and dispel my
>   doubts. What are the meritorious duties of the four several orders?
>   What duties appertain to the Brahmana? What to the Kshatriya? What are
>   the indications of those duties that appertain to the Vaisya? And what
>   kind of duties appertain to the Sudra?'
>
> **"Maheswara said"** -Without doubt, the observance of fasts (i.e., subjugation of the senses) is always the duty of the Brahmana. When
>   the Brahmana succeeds in properly observing all his duties, he attains
>   to identity with Brahma. 1 The proper observance of the duties of
>   Brahmacharya, O goddess, are his ritual. The observance of vows and
>   the investiture with the sacred thread are his other duties. It is by
>   these that he becomes truly regenerate. He becomes a Brahmana for
>   worshipping his preceptors and other seniors as also the deities.
>   Verily, that religion which has for its soul the study of the Vedas is
>   the source of all piety. Even that is the religion which those
>   embodied creatures who are devoted to piety and duty should observe
>   and practise.'
>
> From the beginning it has been said that the duty of the Kshatriya is
>   to protect all creatures. The king is the acquirer of a fixed share of
>   the merits earned by his subjects. By that means the king becomes
>   endued with righteousness. That ruler of men who rules and protects
>   his subjects righteously, acquires, by virtue of the protection he
>   offers to others, many regions of felicity in the world to come. The
>   other duties of a person of the kingly order consist of self-restraint
>   and Vedic study, the pouring of libations on the sacred fire, the
>   making of gifts, study, the bearing of the sacred thread, sacrifices,
>   the performance of religious rites, the support of servants and
>   dependants, and perseverance in acts that have been begun. Another
>   duty of his is to award punishments according to the offences
>   committed. It is also his duty to perform sacrifices and other
>   religious rites according to the ordinances laid down in the Vedas.
>   Adherence to the practice of properly judging the disputes of
>   litigants before him, and a devotion to truthfulness of speech, and
>   interference for aiding the distressed, are the other duties by
>   discharging which the king acquires great glory both here and
>   hereafter. He should also lay down his life on the field of battle,
>   having displayed great prowess on behalf of kine and Brahmanas
>
> The duties of the Vaisya always consist of the keeping of cattle and
>   agriculture, the pouring of libations on the sacred fire, the making
>   of gifts, and study. Trade, walking in the path of righteousness,
>   hospitality, peacefulness, self-restraint, welcoming of Brahmanas, and
>   renouncing things (in favour of Brahmanas), are the other eternal
>   duties of the Vaisya. The Vaisya, engaged in trade and walking in the
>   path of righteousness, should never sell sesame and perfumery and
>   juices or liquid substances. He should discharge the duties of
>   hospitality towards all. He is at liberty to pursue religion and
>   wealth and pleasure according.
>
> The service of the three regenerate classes constitutes the high duty
>   of the Sudra. That Sudra who is truthful in speech and who has subdued
>   his senses is regarded as having acquired meritorious penances.
>   Verily, the Sudra, who having got a guest, discharges the duties of
>   hospitality towards him, is regarded as acquiring the merit of high
>   penances. That intelligent Sudra whose conduct is righteous and who
>   worships the deities and Brahmanas, becomes endued with the desirable
>   rewards of righteousness.

---

Besides that Uma also is asking some personal questions to Maheshwara -some of them are.

She asked why Lord Shiva has choose Nandi (Bull as his vehicle). -

> with great beauty, why is it that thou hast selected a bovine bull for
>   thy vehicle?'Uma said, 'When, O foremost of all creatures, there are
>   so many excellent vehicles endued

Uma asked why Shiva resides in cremation grounds?

> Uma said, 'Thou hast many abodes in heaven, of diverse forms and
>   possessed of every comfort and luxury. Why, O holy one, dost thou
>   reside in the crematorium, abandoning all those delightful mansions?

And the answers given By Lord Shiva are. -

> "Maheswara said, 'In the days of yore, the Grandsire Brahma created
>   the celestial cow Surabhi yielding abundant milk. After her creation
>   there sprang from her a large number of kine all of which yielded
>   copious quantities of milk sweet as nectar. Once on a time a quantity
>   of froth fell from the mouth of one of her calves on my body. I was
>   enraged at this and my wrath scorched all the kine which thereupon
>   became diversified in hue. I was then pacified by the Master of all
>   the worlds, viz., Brahma, conversant with all topics. It was he who
>   gave me this bull both as a vehicle for bearing me and as a device on
>   my banner.'
>
> P. 290"Maheswara said, 'I always wander over the whole earth in search
>   of a sacred spot. I do not, however, see any spot that is more sacred
>   than the crematorium. Hence, of all abodes, the crematorium pleases my
>   heart most, shaded that it generally is by branches of the banian and
>   adorned with torn garlands of flowers. O thou of sweet smiles, the
>   multitudes of ghostly beings that are my companions love to reside in
>   such spots. I do not like, O goddess, to reside anywhere without those
>   ghostly creatures being by my side. Hence, the crematorium is a sacred
>   abode to me. Indeed, O auspicious lady, it seems to me to be the very
>   heaven. Highly sacred and possessed of great merit, the crematorium is
>   much applauded by persons desirous of having holy abodes.'

---

## What are the some parvas of Mahabharata mentions about lord shiva's deeds?

There are many a deeds of Lord Shiva mentioned in Mahabharata and listing all of them will make pretty broad. But I am posting some.

- Battle between Lord Shiva and Arjuna and Lord Shiva defeating Arjuna as Kairata and providing him PashupatastraIn . [**Kairata Parva -Chapter XXXIX**](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03039.htm)
- Lord Shiva giving boon to Amba about her wish to slay Bhishma and birth of Shikhnadi. 
  [**Uluka Dutagamana Parva - Section CXC**](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05190.htm)
- Lord Shiva's giving of Khadga or sword to Ashvatthama upon his request.- [**Sauptika Parva**](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m10/m10007.htm)  Chapter 7
- Lord Shiva as Virbhadra destroying Daksha Yajna- - [**Mokshadharma Parva**](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b110.htm) Mokshadharma Parva - SECTION CCLXXXIII -

Comment: What is the exact reason behind Lord Shiva had destroyed the yagya of daksha bcoz here the story was quite different. Can you please tell me @SwiftPushkar